# Compare two differently sized data frames and return the unique values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, bookers and non_bookers. Each frame has a common column which acts as a unique identifier for a customer (column is called visitorid). In the bookers frame, each row contains a unique customer however in non_bookers each row does not contain a unique customer, customer x could appear any number of times in this frame.

Both data frames share all the same columns except bookers has 2445 rows and non_bookers has 47555 rows. The image below shows the customer id's in the bookers data frame.

[image: bookers dataframe]

non_bookers contains rows which have the same customer id's that are found in bookers. The image below is a list of customer id's contained in the non_bookers data frame.

[image: non_bookers]

How can I return a data frame which is the non_bookers data frame, but with the customer id's that match those found in bookers removed? So for example, id number 2147090566 in the bookers data frame is also in the non_bookers data frame, I want to return a data frame which will have that id number removed from the non_bookers data frame. Therefore any id in found in bookers, should not be in non_bookers.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some example data and the desired result. That will make it easier.

Comment: It's quite unclear your description of your dfs, but generally I think the following should work `non_bookers[~non_bookers['customerid'].isin(bookers['customerid'])]`

Comment: Thanks Ed, your code works.